# Problema con Highlight Color extension en VS Code

Tags: vscode, extensiones

Cada vez que abro VS Code

Me sale una notificación que dice:

The extension  host has stopped unexpectedly

Y al abrir el Developer Tool me aparece esto:

%cError: Import "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap" could not be resolved.%c    at File.load (D:\Projects\vscode-ext-color-highlight\node_modules\file-importer\index.js:130:1)%c    at D:\Projects\vscode-ext-color-highlight\node_modules\file-importer\index.js:136:1%c    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:172:21)

¿Alguien sasbe como corregirlo?

Comment: Qué versión de VSCode tienes instalado? entiendo que la versión de windows, de todas formas yo probaría a eliminar por completo la extensión y volver a instalarla.

Comment: la más reciente: 1.54.3
Y hay forma de eliminar una extención al 100%?
Es que ya la desinstalé y la reinstalé.  reinicié mi pc  y me sigue marcando el mismo  error, sin pasar antes por el  aviso

Comment: Una vez desinstalas la extensión, dirigete a %USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions y elimina la carpeta que corresponda al módulo (en caso de que esta exista todavía)

Comment: Ya me aseguré que no  existe carpeta alguna de esa axtension  y me sigue apareciendo  ese problema